# Save As "Web Page, Complete" javascript is failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, browser, slick.js

JavaScript is not working, when I save the webpage, i followed below steps

1. Right click and click on "Save As" on web Page in chrome.
2. Used "File Type" as "WebPage, complete".

In the website, they used [Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and complete carousel functionality got broken. Here all CSS styles and images are fine.

Comment: of course it's not working. stuff that requires javascript might break when loading it from such a saved dump.

Comment: Is there any way to handle js files, i can see all  js files are saved  and they are loading.

Comment: you need to manually inspect the page and replace API requests inside the code with proper mocked API responses. this is a tiresome and lengthy progress. unless it's worth the effort i'd advice against saving it as a dump.

Comment: Thank you GottZ. I accept it and here we don't have any API's calls for the data. But   the carousel and mobile view functionality is completely broken because of minified JS file. This file include slick slider, jQuery-magic-scroll libraries.

Comment: There must be errors in the javascript console